# Divide 'bytes' object into chunks in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp

I need to send an array by 'packages' of specific length (say 40 bytes) using `TCP Protocol` and Python's `socket` module.
First I'm generating sample array of `ints`:

```
int_array = [i**2 for i in range(1, 100)]
```

Then I'm converting it into `bytes` object:

```
encoded_array = str(int_array).encode()
```

To check length of `encoded_array` object I'm using `len(encoded_array)` which in this particular case equals 551 bytes.

Say I want to sent packages that are 40 bytes long: this makes full 13 packages and the leftovers from last bytes of `encoded_array`, total of 14 packages. But I can't figure out the method how to divide `bytes` object into smaller `bytes` objects by number of bytes itself. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

I'm also aware that I may be doing it in totally wrong way, so please advise me on how to send 'portioned' data via `TCP` protocol. Maybe there's no need to do this splitting at all?

Comment: The "sockets" or "socket" module?

Comment: Isn't the `struct`module useful for this?

Comment: @MustacheMoses Yes, thanks for noticing, it's 'socket'

Comment: "sys.getsizeof" does not check the length of the bytes, it checks the *size of the bytes object*. If you want the length, you need `len(byte_object)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're, right, I made a fix in description

Comment: So, are you *sure* you want `encoded_array = str(int_array).encode()`? You want to send the *string representation* of a *list of ints* across the socket? (note, it isn't an array)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What I say may sound stupid: I need to send amount of bytes. Doesn't matter what data type is the original input, it may be array, it may be string...

Comment: Yes, but you are sending the *bytes representing a string representing a list*. Is that what you want?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if there's other way to represent list as 'bytes' directly?

Comment: This depends on your use-case. If you *really* need a list, then you are pretty much stuck using some form of serialization, e.g. `pickle` or `json`, in this case where you simply use `str(my_list)`, you'd have to end up using `eval(rec_bytes.decode())` which is not... great. If you could use an `array.array` instead, you could do this more memory efficiently using `socket.recv_into`. If memory and serialization overhead isn't a concern, then you can stick with some form of serialized lists...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bytes can be tricky.

First off, `encoded_array = str(int_array).encode()` is not doing what you think. If you print encoded_array, you'll see that it's literally converting the `to_string` value of int_array to bytes. This is why the first value of encoded_array is `[`

```
>>> encoded_array[:1]
b'['
```

Second, I'm not sure you want `int_array = [i**2 for i in range(1, 100)]` to do what it's doing. It creates values up to 10,000. I'm unsure if you would like for this range to be between 0 and 256 if each element is to represent a byte. I'm going to assume you would like  *some data* to be converted to bytes and split into 40 byte chunks and the data in this case is an array of integers.

First let's convert your int_array into an array of bytes. I'm going to convert each int into a 2 byte value and represent it in hex.

```
>>> hex_array = [x.to_bytes(2, byteorder="big") for x in int_array]
```

Now to split up the data into bytes of 40

```
>>> h
[]

>>> for x in range(0, int(round(len(hex_array)/20))):
...     h.append(hex_array[:20])
...     del hex_array[:20]
```

I'm splitting by 20 because each element holds 2 bytes

Now you'll have an array of max 40 byte collections. Time to join the collections together so we can transmit them!

```
>>> result
[]

>>> for package in h:
...     joined_package = b';'.join(package)
...     result.append(joined_package)
```